# Regex to extract a part of an URL

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the part of an URL ignoring the `http(s)://www.` part of it.

These URLs come from a form that the user fills and multiple formats and errors are expected, here's a sample:

```
http://www.akashicbooks.com 
https://deliciouselsalvador.com
http://altaonline.com
http://https://www.amtb-la.org/
http://https://www.amovacations.com/
http://dornsife.usc.edu/jep
```

I've tried in Google Sheets and Airtable using the `REGEXEXTRACT` formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT({URL},"[^/]+$")
```

But unfortunately, I can't make it work for all the cases:

[image]

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:https?://(?:www\.)?)*(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F7nHHG/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?://(?:www\.)?)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
  - `(?:www\.)?` - an optional sequence of `www.`
- `(.*)` - Group 1: the rest of the string.

With `REGEXEXTRACT`, the output value is the text captured with Group 1.

Comment: Slight addition to @Wiktor's code ..(?:h?https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)*(.*)